# DevExpress RibbonPage added programatically does not show

Tags: merge, devexpress, ribbon-control

I've a RibbonControl in a mdiform and another RibbonControl added at design time in a MDIChildForm. Then in runtime, I add a RibbonPage, with a RibbonGroup and a BarButtonItem. Like this:

```
private void MDIChildForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  BarButtonItem btn = ribbonControl1.Items.CreateButton("Test Button");
  RibbonPageGroup group1 = new RibbonPageGroup("Test Group");
  group1.ItemLinks.Add(btn);
  RibbonPage page1 = new RibbonPage("Test Page");
  page1.Groups.Add(group1);
  ribbonControl1.Pages.Add(page1);
}
```

The "Test Page" isn't visible in the MdiParent. But, when I change the active mdi child form, and the ribbon do the merge, the page appears!

It looks like the page isn't merged until I change the active mdi child form.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I found that the ribbon page was added after the automatic merge. So it doesn't exists at the moment of the merge. I've "resolved" it changing the activemdichild to another form, and then getting back to the child I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, but I think is not the most elegant way to solve it:

```
mainRibbon.UnMergeRibbon();
mainRibbon.MergeRibbon(mdiChildForm.ChildRibbon);
```

A public property to access the child Ribbon was needed.